# str_replace with regex

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

I think this has been done a million times but I can't get the expression right.

I need to `str_replace` an `<input>` element and everything between the  So capture the id and the name enz...

So I thought:

```
<?php 
    $regex = '<input(.*?)>';
    $replacement = '<select>';
    $content = '<input id="id" name="name"/>text';
    $result = str_replace($regex, $replacement, $content);
    echo $result;
?>
```

I know this won't work but I think this should be the right way.

Anyone?

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Comment: [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) support regex? no!, try [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) or xpath

Comment: @Interactive Did you just copy the answer below into the question?!

Comment: It has no sense to edit your question after others gave you the solution. Better search next time.

Comment: Nope just updated it with the right answer!

Comment: @Interactive **"Nope just updated it with the right answer!"** You shouldn't do that, just mark the answer as correct and leave your question untouched, otherwise there's no use for future users.

Comment: Allright! I'll change it

Comment: Worse than using `mysql_` functions or Dreamweaver as IDE, surely is parsing HTML with regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
<?php 
$regex = '#<input(.*?)>#';
$replacement = '<select>';
$content = '<input id="id" name="name"/>text';
$result = preg_replace($regex, $replacement, $content);
echo $result;
```

Comment: @PedroLobito delimiters at `$regex` and `preg_replace` instead of `str_replace`.